# shell script for Centos box

Tags: shell, centos

I am a new to shell scripts and how to write them. I am wanting to write a script that search a specific dir(/mydir) for all files that have an extension .test and then delete them.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: `man find`... No need to write a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /mydir -name '*.test' -delete
```

Find is an incredibly flexible tool. See `man find` for a rundown on all the things it can do.